# How to update Chrome Extension without alerting the users

Tags: google-chrome

How to update Chrome Extension without alerting the users? For example I have a extension and I must change everyday info in it and I don't want to update the app version or to upload it again when I need to change some info in it.. so how can I make to change info in my chrome extension I mean to modify the .html file without updating the version? I can use a external web page to show up in my extension and to update the info from my website everytime I need updates? this is a option too.. but I don't know if the guys from google extensions accept this. Please help me.

Comment: You should think vice versa, i.e. how to get updated JavaScript data, instead of how to update the extension.

Comment: I want to update only what's in .html file.

Comment: Same, change contents using JavaScript and in the extension detect it and store the data.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. That's why I asked for help.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy can you help me?

Comment: any help??? please?